# How to specify scss @import name in node package?

Tags: npm, sass

The documentation for Bootstrap's node package says to simply add `@import "bootstrap";` to my scss file to include Bootstrap's scss.

When writing my own node package, how do I get this functionality?

For instance, I have a package called *foobar*. How can I set it up so that it will know where to grab my package's scss simply by putting `@import "foo";` in my main scss file?

Answer (score 0):

If the name of your main SCSS file is foo.scss, it works. Check here for more information: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this does not work.To clarify, the scss file I want to import in my project is nested in the node_modules directory. How to I refer to `foo.scss` in the node_modules from within my project's main scss file?

Essentially what I think I'm looking for is a way to tell @import to go search in other directories.